# PhantomJS page.injectJs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm currently trying to write the page source code into a text file by a URL. Everything works well, but I want to additionally inject a JavaScript file. The problem is that the file does not include properly. Only the last pages that are loaded, but others are incomplete.

```
//phantomjs C:\PhantomJS\Script\test1.js

var fs = require('fs');
var numeroEpisode = 0;
var maxEpisode = 10;
var fichierLien = fs.read('C:\\PhantomJS\\Fichier\\lien.txt');
var ListeLien = fichierLien.split(/[\n]/);

var page = require('webpage').create();

function GetPage()
{
    if (numeroEpisode > maxEpisode) 
    { 
        phantom.exit();
    }
    page.open(ListeLien[numeroEpisode], function(status)
    {
        if(status !== 'success')
        {
            console.log('Impossible de charger la page.');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('URL: '+ListeLien[numeroEpisode]+'');
            page.injectJs('http://mylink.com', function() { });
            var path = 'C:\\PhantomJS\\Fichier\\episode_'+numeroEpisode+'.html';
            fs.write(path, page.content, 'w');
            setTimeout(GetPage, 15000); // run again in 15 seconds
            numeroEpisode++;
        }   
    });
}
GetPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up [`page.injectJs()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) and [`page.includeJs()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html).

**`injectJs(filename)`:** Loads a local JavaScript file into the page and evaluates it synchronously.

**`includeJs(url, callback)`:** Loads a remote JavaScript file from the specified URL and evaluates it. Since it has to request a remote resource, this is done asynchronously. The passed callback is called as soon as the operation finished. If you don't use the callback, your code will most likely run before the remote JavaScript was included. Use that callback:

```
page.includeJs('http://mylink.com', function() {
    var path = 'C:\\PhantomJS\\Fichier\\episode_'+numeroEpisode+'.html';
    fs.write(path, page.content, 'w');
    numeroEpisode++;
    setTimeout(GetPage, 15000); // run again in 15 seconds
});
```

Since the JavaScript that you load changes something on the page, you probably need to load it after all the pages script have run. If this is a JavaScript heavy page, then you need to wait a little. You can wait a static amount of time:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    page.includeJs('http://mylink.com', function() {
        //...
    });
}, 5000); // 5 seconds
```

or utilize [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to wait until an element appears that denotes that the page is completely loaded. This can be very tricky sometimes.

---

If you still want to use `injectJs()` instead of `includeJs()` (for example because of its synchronous nature), then you need to download the external JavaScript file to your machine and then you can use `injectJs()`.

Comment: I need to use injectJs because the file and externally, I want to somehow change a site to include the source code that features differently.
I still have the same problem, the first pages do not load completely, can be that pages load and too fast?

Is there a function to wait until the page is loaded before another load ?    Anyway thank you for all the help you have given me!

Comment: Then you need to download the file to your machine. Only then you can use `page.injectJs()`. You could wait a little longer with `page.includeJs('http://mylink.com', function() { setTimeout(function(){ var path...}, 5000)});`

Comment: I come to test with includeJs and it work, but the problem with the loading page is always here

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by *"problem with the loading page"*. Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: The problem with the page loading is that the page is not the time to be completely loaded

Comment: Then either wait a static amount of time with `setTimeout()` or use `waitFor()` to wait until a specific element is present that denotes that the page is complete. I've extended my answer with an example.

Comment: when the page is loaded its displays some error, but even with the waitfor function pages are not loaded set apart the last page that displays errors and load but loaded

Comment: error when page loaded correctly: https://gist.github.com/Culvanen/e34fbb2f5e595a505a07

Comment: It happens sometimes that some advertisement script don't run in PhantomJS. I cannot make out what the issue is. Have you tried to `page.render(filename)` the page to see in what state it is in?

Comment: so, there is no solution to my problem?

Comment: Probably there is. What PhantomJS version do you use by the way? If you're using PhantomJS 1.x, have you tried PhantomJS 2?

Comment: I use phantomJS 2.0.0

Comment: You can also try PhantomJS 1.9.8, because v2.0.0 doesn't throw all errors.

Comment: The code seems not compatible, I despair, think that what I want is feasible in PHP ?